# Cloudify:: uninstallation-application fails

Tags: cloudify

To uninstall an application I called uninstall-application app-name from the cloudify prompt in a local cloud environment. However the uninstall is unsuccessful. The log file shows following exception.

2013-10-14 13:06:50,537 rest [1] INFO [org.cloudifysource.rest.controllers.ServiceController] - Removing all application scope attributes for application 
2013-10-14 13:06:50,542 rest [1] WARNING [org.openspaces.admin.internal.admin.DefaultAdmin] - Failed to execute: org.openspaces.admin.internal.gsm.DefaultGridServiceManager$3@70b1ec8b - org.openspaces.admin.AdminException: Failed to undeploy processing unit [app-name]; Caused by: org.openspaces.admin.AdminException: Failed to undeploy processing unit [app-name]
        at org.openspaces.admin.internal.gsm.DefaultGridServiceManager.undeployProcessingUnit(DefaultGridServiceManager.java:279)
        at org.openspaces.admin.internal.gsm.DefaultGridServiceManager$3.run(DefaultGridServiceManager.java:799)
        at org.openspaces.admin.internal.admin.DefaultAdmin$LoggerRunnable.run(DefaultAdmin.java:2077)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.jini.rio.core.OperationalStringException: GSM not found
        at org.jini.rio.monitor.ProvisionMonitorImpl.undeploy(ProvisionMonitorImpl.java:601)
        at org.jini.rio.monitor.ProvisionMonitorAdminImpl.undeploy(ProvisionMonitorAdminImpl.java:126)
        at org.jini.rio.monitor.DeployAdminGigaspacesMethodinternalInvoke7.internalInvoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.gigaspaces.internal.reflection.fast.AbstractMethod.invoke(AbstractMethod.java:41)
        at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.LRMIRuntime.invoked(LRMIRuntime.java:450)
        at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Pivot.consumeAndHandleRequest(Pivot.java:557)
        at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Pivot.handleRequest(Pivot.java:658)
        at com.gigaspaces.lrmi.nio.Pivot$ChannelEntryTask.run(Pivot.java:196)
        ... 3 more

2013-10-14 13:06:51,544 rest [1] INFO [org.cloudifysource.rest.util.RestPollingRunnable] - undeployAndWait for processing unit  has not finished yet
@

Eventually the operation times out. Post that I can not even teardown the local cloud. The only way to come out of this is the reboot the system. Appreciate some help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

The following error:

```
Caused by: org.jini.rio.core.OperationalStringException: GSM not found at org.jini.rio.monitor.ProvisionMonitorImpl.undeploy
```

indicates that one of the Cloudify management components was missing. It may have crashed earlier, or perhaps the local machine was running at 100% CPU, causing local components to not respond to each other.

In an actual cloud deployment, this would cause the Cloudify agent to restart the failed component, but in the local-cloud environment the agent and the other management components run in the same process to conserve memory and speed up start-up time.